Event priority of an object with more than one class
When more than one event handler is bound to an element, how is it determined which one is triggered first?
I have more than one class in an object.what I want to do is to decide which class will run first when the button is clicked.each class prepares some code for the next class to run.
Currently, each event does not work in the order I want.
<button class="btn-one btn-two btn-three">list</button>

If I put the events in the order I want in the logic that the event of the first incoming service runs first, yes, what I want happens. However, these events are not in a single js file, so putting the js files in order will cause other problems.
$('.btn-one').off('click');
$(document).on('click', '.btn-one', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
});

$('.btn-two').off('click');
$(document).on('click', '.btn-two', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.btn-three').off('click');
$(document).on('click', '.btn-three', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

I provided control by making hasClass in a single event. However, this priority assignment did not work in the order I wanted, although I wrote it in the order I wanted in html.
<button class="btn-three btn-one btn-two">list</button>

$('.btn-three, .btn-one, .btn-two').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('btn-one')) {
        // do stuff
    } else if ($this.hasClass('btn-two')) {
        // do other stuff
    } else if ($this.hasClass('btn-three')) {
    
    }
});

or I tried this but this will not work when there are more than two classes
/* Handler1 - */ $(document).on('click', 'btn-one', function....)
/* Handler2 - */ $('btn-two').on('click', function....)
/* Handler3 - */ $('btn-three').on('click', function....)

In the example above, handler 2 is always called before handler 1, but what happens when handler 3 is called?
edit:
I found this example while doing research, it helped a little, but it only determines the first class, the next classes work in the order of ten events, as I said, my events are not in a single js file, but in mixed files.
jQuery event handlers always execute in order they were bound - any way around this?
https://jsfiddle.net/x8Na8/2/
https://jsfiddle.net/j6HP5/2/

They're triggered in the order that you called .on().

Don't use else if if you want to run the codes for all the classes. else if makes the conditions exclusive, it only executes the first matching condition.

The order of classes in the class= attribute is not generally significant. If you care about the order, you will need to loop over the elements of this.classList.

If you have such a question, then, most likely, you are doing something wrong...
But still you can manipulate $._data. For example, in your particular case, I invented something like this:


$(document).on('click', '.btn', function (e) {
  if ($(e.currentTarget).data('triggered')) {
    $(e.currentTarget).data('triggered', false);
    return;
  }
  const selector = $('[name="selector"]:checked').val();

  const clicks = $._data(e.delegateTarget, 'events').click;

  const normalClicks = [...$._data(e.delegateTarget, 'events').click];
  normalClicks.delegateCount = clicks.delegateCount;

  const index = clicks.findIndex(event => event.selector === selector);
  if (index !== -1) {
    const [event] = clicks.splice(index, 1);
    clicks.unshift(event);
  }
  $._data(e.delegateTarget, 'events').click = clicks;
  $(e.currentTarget).data('triggered', true).trigger('click');
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  $._data(e.delegateTarget, 'events').click = normalClicks;
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn-one', function (e) {
  console.log('.btn-one');
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn-two', function () {
  console.log('.btn-two');
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn-three', function () {
  console.log('.btn-three');
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="radio" value=".btn-one" name="selector">.btn-one
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" value=".btn-two" name="selector" checked>.btn-two
</label><label>
  <input type="radio" value=".btn-three" name="selector">.btn-three
</label>
<button class="btn btn-one btn-two btn-three">list</button>



